# Как отключить подсказки о сложности кода в VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Мне над каждоей моей функцией, условной конструкцией VS code пишет вот такие подсказки: "complexity is 5 everything is cool", т.е - оценивает сложность кода, как их отключить?

Comment: Какой язык программирования? Если выключить все расширения - все равно пишет?

Comment: В js, tsx файлах пишет

Comment: Это явно, какое-то расширение, только не знаю, какое

Comment: Нашел, плагин для node установил в виде зависимости другой плагин и он и подсвечивал, благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотри тут https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense. Попробуй установить это поле в файле settings.json

```
{"editor.quickSuggestions": false}
```